# How to add a custom authentication provider

Tags: authentication, windows-ce

Windows CE 5.0 provides several [security support providers][1]:

- Kerberos Security Support Provider
- NTLM Security Support Provider
- Schannel Security Support Provider
- Negotiate Security Support Provider

I need to provide my own security support provider since I need to migrate the authentication information from one version of my Windows CE platform to the next version.

The NTLM authentication can store password hashes in the registry. But these are invalid when you upgrade to the next SYSGENed platform. Therefore I want o add a custom authentication provider. How can this be implemented?